Electricity consumption for 12000btu a/c for 120 H monthly usage
I have a home office room like so:
Height - 9 feet
length - 13 feet
width - 10 feet
I want to know how much electricity(KWh) it will consume if I install a 12000 btu Inverter air conditioner for 120 H monthly.

None if the outside temperature matches the A/C setpoint. Otherwise it will depend on whether you're heating or cooling, the temperature difference between inside and outside and the coefficient of performance. You should move the question to https://diy.stackexchange.com, provide the missing details and your location. You could also work out the room volume and post that in your question to save others the trouble.

Google:  12000btu to W

You will need the nameplate power and/or current draw since 12000 BTU is only the (probably as optimistic as the manufacturer can legally state) performance number; the efficiency is unknown.
Even then, that will only give you an upper bound on energy consumption since nameplate values are maximums; you will need a power meter to find the actual current draw.
And that number will itself be another approximation since you'll need to guess at the cooling-degree-hours the AC unit is working against, the insulation in your walls, what kind of glass is in your windows, etc etc etc.
You may be able to find an online calculator that will do this for you. Maybe from your state government, the EPA, your power company, etc. But it will still be a rough approximation.

I just need to get a rough estimation only using my figures above.
